# Apache - Serving png as text / html

Tags: apache, php-7.2, laravel-6

The server log says:

```
[04/Nov/2019:23:11:23 +0100] "GET /imgs/flags/fr.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2173 "http://XXXXX.com/user/start" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3959.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

However, they are being served as text:

[image]

This is only happening in production though... in localhost it works fine.

This image loads ok: `/imgs/logo_only_transparent.png`

This image does not load: `/imgs/flags/es.png`

Using Ubuntu 18.04, php 7.2, Laravel 6, Vue 2.x

What am I missing?

From the network tab:

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1205
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 04 Nov 2019 22:11:23 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkFcL3lRY2JcL0o1R0VyNmRzeXdHcytsQT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJMNWoyeUUyeW1lMG4zOFNRWnVDWG5jRU1FOFU2bVRuTzl6WmZqQlwvVGFXdnhQWVBVM29vbW1JTEszMldlXC9ra1IiLCJtYWMiOiJjM2JmODA4M2RiODVjZjJjODM5NTliYTFiMzI3NzU2ZDk0YjQwNmY3YTU3YzE1NmE3NzI3ZDM2YTIxODQ2YTY3In0%3D; expires=Tue, 05-Nov-2019 00:11:23 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
```

**EDIT (Solved):** The reason was that the file is named `ES.png` no `es.png`. Apparently this is not an issue when running XAMPP in Windows but it when running it in Ubuntu.

Comment: And the body contains a png or a html? Please show the response headers too

Comment: It says there is no response data